# Grunt Concat same file multiple times

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, concatenation

I'd like to use `grunt-contrib-concat` for application frontend HTML templating purposes and this would be useful for me.

I'd like to define page partials and and concatenate them inside an output file that is going to be compiled by handlebars.

I've got everything set up, however Concat doesn't allow me to use the same file more than once.

Basically concat is filtering the sources so they don't occur more than once. The second `partial1.hbs` will not be concatenated.

```
pageconcat: {
    src: [
       'app/templates/partial1.hbs',
       'app/templates/partial2.hbs',
       'app/templates/partial1.hbs'
    ],
    dest: 'app/result.hbs'
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

### Update 1

After playing around with grunt's console output function, I was able to debug (of some sort) the concat plugin. Here's what I found out: The input array is deduplicated by **grunt** for some reason.

### Update 2

The deduplication occurs in the foreach file loop that grunt uses. I've managed to bypass that (see answer). I do not know how reliable my solution is but it's a workaround and it works well if you don't put the wrong input.

Comment: What do you mean by "Concat doesn't allow me to use the same file more than once"?

Comment: @romuleald I've added the structure I was talking about. Basically concat is filtering the sources so they don't occur more than once.  The second `partial1.hbs` will not be concatenated

Comment: @meffect that comment was totally unnecessary and did not help in any way.

Comment: I'm surprised that grunt-contrib-concat is working than anything else but JS. If you do the same thing but with JS files, is it the same result?

Comment: @romuleald It's the same. Maybe someone knows what needs to be changed inside the concat.js file to make it work without the filtering?

Comment: If you cheat by adding a ? at the end of file?

Comment: @romuleald Already tried. Doesn't include the file at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

After some debugging I came up with a solution. Certainly not the best, but it works fine, as it should.

I edited the **concat.js** plugin file inside the node_modules folder the following way:

```
grunt.registerMultiTask('concat', ...){
    var self = this;

    //several lines of code
    //...

    //replace f.src.filter(..) wtih
    self.data.src.filter(..);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use the file array format to set up two different source sets.  Something like this:

```
{
    "files": [{
        "src": [
            "app/templates/partial1.hbs",
            "app/templates/partial2.hbs"
        ],
        "dest": "app/result.hbs"
    }, {
        "src": [
            "app/result.hbs",
            "app/templates/partial1.hbs"
        ],
        "dest": "app/result.hbs"
    }]
}
```

---

added "app/result.hbs" to second source set, as was pointed out in the comments.
Thanks.

Comment: You might have to set `"src": ["app/result.hbs", "app/templates/partial1.hbs"]` for the second one.

Comment: It would be advisable @GrozavAlexIoan to create an issue in the appropriate repository for grunt-contrib-concat. They'll probably be able to take this forward. And maybe implement an option to allow for repeat if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: Alright, added an issue. Thank you for the suggestion. Meanwhile I'll try to see if I can make the changes myself and I'll post an update here if yes.

Comment: I've got an answer saying that grunt does the deduplication, not concat. Which means there's probably no way to achieve this through plugin settings.